# Containerizing a flask application that uses PYODBC

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, flask, odbc

I am trying to create a container and it's telling me that the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server can't be opened. here is the container but I have tried many different containers. This is the code that throws the error.

```
class Database:
    @staticmethod
    def _get_connection_string_from_secrets(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            db = data['database']
            
            connection_string = (f"Driver={{{db['driver']}}};"
                                 f"Server={db['server']};"
                                 f"Database={db['database_name']};"
                                 f"Uid={db['uid']};"
                                 f"Pwd={db['pwd']};"
                                 f"Encrypt={db['encrypt']};"
                                 f"TrustServerCertificate={db['trust_server_certificate']};"
                                 f"Timeout={db['connection_timeout']};")

            return connection_string
```

```
# Use an official Ubuntu as a base image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Set environment variables to non-interactive (this avoids some prompts)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Install Python and pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-dev \
    python3-tk\
    unixodbc-dev \
    g++ 

# Install Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server
RUN apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | apt-key add -
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(. /etc/os-release; echo $VERSION_ID)/prod.list
RUN mv prod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /usr/src/app
COPY . .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 5555

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World



CMD ["python3", "runserver.py"]
```

It is in exactly the correct place though.

```
root@f985ac7c4261:/usr/src/app# odbcinst -q -d
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
root@f985ac7c4261:/usr/src/app# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.9
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
root@f985ac7c4261:/usr/src/app# cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.5.1
UsageCount=1
```

This is the stack trace

````
  File "/usr/src/app/runserver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ProteinViewer import app  # Import the 'app' object from your app module
  File "/usr/src/app/ProteinViewer/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import views
  File "/usr/src/app/views.py", line 53, in <module>
    protein_name_map = Database.get_protein_name_map();
  File "/usr/src/app/Database.py", line 149, in get_protein_name_map
    temps = Database.execute_query(sql, False)
  File "/usr/src/app/Database.py", line 93, in execute_query
    connection = Database.get_connection()
  File "/usr/src/app/Database.py", line 39, in get_connection
    return pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
root@8508e47d6825:/usr/src/app# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/
root@8508e47d6825:/usr/src/app# python3 runserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/runserver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ProteinViewer import app  # Import the 'app' object from your app module
  File "/usr/src/app/ProteinViewer/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import views
  File "/usr/src/app/views.py", line 53, in <module>
    protein_name_map = Database.get_protein_name_map();
  File "/usr/src/app/Database.py", line 149, in get_protein_name_map
    temps = Database.execute_query(sql, False)
  File "/usr/src/app/Database.py", line 93, in execute_query
    connection = Database.get_connection()
  File "/usr/src/app/Database.py", line 39, in get_connection
    return pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")```
````

I have also run a variety of other commands to make sure that the ODBC driver is fine. I have also switched Linux distros, I am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Aside... `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive` is discouraged because it persists beyond the image build phase. In a pinch use `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`, but it's preferred to use it in a targeted manner only on the commands where it is required, e.g.: `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get ...`

Comment: Did you notice a warning while doing the second `apt-get` update in your build, `W: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.`? This is because the `apt-key` utility is deprecated as of Ubuntu 22.04. You'll need to `apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes curl gnupg2` before following [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).